# How to see if a class is an instance of another class without creating either class?

Tags: php

I have two classes.

I want to check if a class is an instance of another class without initializing either of them.

With the function `is_subclass_of` and when using `instanceOf` you have to initialize the sub class.

```
<?php

$classPath = 'app/foo/bar';
$subClassPath = 'app/foo/foo'; // Inherits from $classPath

// This is what I want to do but doesn't work.
echo $subClassPath instanceOf $classPath;

// Works
echo (new $subClassPath()) instanceOf $classPath;
```

Comment: `is_subclass_of` does not require instances.

Comment: A class never is a child of another class. It may extend another class. You need to differ between a class which is an implementation and an object which is the instantiation of a class. Objects can have children, classes not.

Comment: @JonStirling Thanks, I found my problem was the slashes went the wrong way.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks, I changed the wording to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

`is_subclass_of` requires your slashes to go the other way.

```
$classPath = 'app\foo\bar';
$subClassPath = 'app\foo\foo'; // Inherits from $classPath

// Works
echo is_subclass_of($subClassPath $classPath);
```